# location.href = 'URL' redirects to a new page not a new website

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a project that involves redirecting to another website. I am having trouble doing that.

Here is my code

```js
document.getElementById("ContinueToWeb").onclick = function () {
   location.href = "google.com";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Some code here-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Some code here-->
    <button id="ContinueToWeb">Continue</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it redirects from `c:/folder/index.html` to `c:/folder/google.com` even though I am telling it to go from `c:/folder/index.html` to `google.com`. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: Change the URL to `https://google.com`

Comment: If you told it go go to `index2.html` would you expect it to go to `http://index2.html`?

Comment: yes I would expect it to go to HTTP://index2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the protocol for the link or else it defaults to what the site is using which is your local filesystem. Use `https://www.google.com` instead